# how to make state work in only one div inside map function in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to change the color of those message whose mark state variable is true after clicking the button which updates the value of mark from false to true in my database.

but what happening is when i click on one message, all the messages color goes from blue to green. I want change the color of only that message

What can be the solution?

```
const [markState, setMarkState] = useState(false);
const markonclickHandler = async (id) => {
    const dataRaw = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/contactformunreadmessage/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        authToken: authToken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ mark: true }),
    });
    const data = await dataRaw.json();
    setMarkState(data.success);
```

In jsx

```
<div className="p-8 flex flex-wrap font-mono">
            {readMessages.map((message) => {
              return (
           </div>
                  {markState ? (
                    <button
                      className=" font-serif text-green-600 cursor-pointer text-right"
                    >
                      marked as read
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <button
                      onClick={() => markonclickHandler(message._id)}
                      className=" font-serif text-blue-600 cursor-pointer text-right"
                    >
                      mark as read
                    </button>
                  )}
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have a single `markState` variable for the whole list of `readMessages`, changing `markState` will modify the button selection for all of the children.

To put it simply, you need to maintain `markState` for every child of `readMessages` array.

For ex:

```
const Message = ({ message }) => {
  const [markState, setMarkState] = useState(false)
  // your markonclickHandler can live here as such
  // but I highly recommend you to move it to a some state management tool
  const markonclickHandler = async (id) => {
    const dataRaw = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/contactformunreadmessage/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        authToken: authToken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ mark: true }),
    })
    const data = await dataRaw.json()
    setMarkState(data.success)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {markState ? (
        <button className=" font-serif text-green-600 cursor-pointer text-right">
          marked as read
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button
          onClick={() => markonclickHandler(message._id)}
          className=" font-serif text-blue-600 cursor-pointer text-right"
        >
          mark as read
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

<div className="p-8 flex flex-wrap font-mono">
  {readMessages.map((message) => {
    return <Message message={message} key={message._id} />
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: how can we define state inside a map function

Comment: updated the above code!